# MySQL Workbench works and phpmyadmin does not

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

About 2-3 weeks ago I stopped using phpmyadmin and started using MySQL Workbench. Now, I can't connect to phpmyadmin. I tried connecting from two different computers and from the server. Tried connecting with at least 4 users and root. I am suspecting that this is Workbench's fault. During the time I used Workbench I made some changes to user privileges, but don't remember the specifics. I get "Wrong username/password".

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Wrong username/password :D

Comment: I edited question for additional information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396494/linking-mysql-workbench-to-my-remote-server

Comment: I am connecting with Workbench to Linux server from Windows 7.

Comment: I also said that I tried to connect from server, THAT MEANS ITS LOCALHOST. Does not work.

Comment: I have a user that has % as host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some of the comments have been deleted, but judging by what's left there was a suggestion for you to check your permissions for your user with hostname localhost, and it appears you did not understand that `%` is *not* the same as `localhost`. Many installations come with several root users, one for host `localhost`, one for host `%`, and sometimes a third for `127.0.0.1`. This is normal and part of how MySQL handles permissions. TCP/IP connections match `%`, socket connections do not (they use `localhost`).

Another thing that's important to realize is that, when using phpMyAdmin, it doesn't matter what client machine you're using; what matters is what machine is the web server, since that's where the requests to MySQL come from. So you can easily get a bit confused if using a remote machine to connect to a web server running on the same machine via sockets to the MySQL server -- even though you're on a remote machine from the MySQL server, in this case it appears as a localhost connection to MySQL.

Anyway, very likely what happened was you were "cleaning up" extra users and removed one that had the opposite host value (either `%` or `localhost`); I'd simply recreate your user with the other host. That should clear it up for you.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't aware that the % doesn't include localhost. 

Since I didn't need mysql since last year this wasn't a problem (and I didn't log in to this account). So accepted... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks for the feedback, I'm glad it worked.